# Android Facebook App

Tags: android, facebook, image-gallery, android-gallery

I want to create an Image Stream like in the Facebook app Dashboard. Where users can scroll thru the images Horizontally and on clicking an image it should open a Web view with Zoom capability.

Is there any open source project with which i can accomplish the same ?

[image]

Can some one guide me how to Achieve the Gallery View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is Gallery View layout, take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) tutorial

Comment: @Harasha M V: you might also like to have a look on [Fedor's Lazy Loading of Images over Internet](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3068012/593709)